# CSS Underlay a previous div

Tags: html, css, position

Sorry if the question is a little vague, I found it quite hard to title. Anyway, I am currently creating a new design and I have hit an issue, I basically want one div to start underneath another, as I am using rounded edges on the div before and want to cover up the whitespace.

I am able to get the div to underlay, however when I set the z-index it becomes the bottom element and the interaction with links etc can't be done. (e.g links can't be clicked, can't highlight text)

To better explain, I have created this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdQWu/) link, it shows exactly what I am trying to do. Try clicking the link, it will simply not work.

The code on the JSFiddle is as follows:

```
#div-1, #div-2 {
width: 350px;
border-radius: 0 0 16px 16px;
}

#div-1 {
background-color: grey;
}

#div-2 {
background-color: black;
position: relative;
z-index: -1;
margin-top:-25px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, and if you would like me to clarify anything please do ask.

Thanks,

Jake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Amn7S/

Dont use `z-index:-1;` use `z-index:1;` and `z-index:2;` then it works.

```
#div-1 {
    background-color: grey;
    z-index:2;
    position:relative;
}

#div-2 {
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    margin-top:-25px;
z-index:1;    
}
```

Comment: Ahh! Just realised what I did now. So what I was doing was placing div-2 below all other elements, **including body** which in turn meant it was below everything. So I assume that is why it happened, thanks this works perfectly!

Comment: yes, you also didnt relatively position the grey div, z-index always needs relative position.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have learnt something today: z-index requires a relative position. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

instead using z-index-1; you should use **positive z-index** and tell each div where to stand.

http://jsfiddle.net/wdQWu/3/

```
#div-1, #div-2 {
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 0 0 16px 16px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
#div-1 {
    background-color: grey;
}
#div-2 {
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top:-26px;
}
```

oups, little late, answer already there :)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `z-index` of the link to be above the 2nd div

Comment: In my actual design the links have their own div, and I set the z-index of the div to 99999 and it still didn't allow me to click the link or make any interaction with the text

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe ?

http://jsfiddle.net/wdQWu/1/

I've used a div with a class wrapper as you can see in the code.

```
.wrapper {
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 0 0 16px 16px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Hope it's useful..